# Entity Framework - Duplicate parent(one) when create new child(many)

Tags: entity-framework

Because my english is not good,  I just straight to the point.
Why record Company in database create new record and Customer record refer to new Company record?
Thanks for help :)

```
public class Company : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}

public class EFRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
{
    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    protected BenzineFleetContext Context
    {
        get { return (BenzineFleetContext) UnitOfWork; }
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TEntity> GetDbSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        GetDbSet<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void SaveChanges()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

    //Save
```

var cus = new Customer {Company = SelectedCompany}

```
    _srv.Add(cus);
    _srv.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: There are some relation and other things, may...
Can you specify clearly what exactly you want to do?

Comment: i want to create new customer, customer.Company = SelectedCompany from database

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you are adding entity via `DbSet<T>.Add` method, then entity and all it's referenced entities which not in context yet, will be marked as `Added` in ChangeTracker. That's why new company is added (looks like company is not attached to context):

```
var customer = new Customer {Company = SelectedCompany}
context.Customers.Add(customer);
// at this point customer state will be Added
// company state also will be Added
context.SaveChanges();
```

To avoid such behavior, attach company to context before adding new customer:

```
var customer = new Customer {Company = SelectedCompany}
context.Companies.Attach(SelectedCompany);
context.Customers.Add(customer);
// at this point customer state will be Added
// company state will be Unchanged (if you haven't change it)
context.SaveChanges();
```

Another way is maintaining states manually:

```
var customer = new Customer {Company = SelectedCompany}
context.Customers.Add(customer);
context.Entry(SelectedCompany).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
// at this point customer state will be Added
// company state will be Unchanged
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: But in other method, i add Card refer to Customer same with add Customer refer Company, it's not create a duplicate record.

Comment: @yovierayz looks like record is in context in that case

Comment: it turns out the problem was in the addition of company list, I create a new object twice companies list. But the way, thanks for your help, i will apply your example to improve my code :)

Answer (score -2):

You can see [this](http://www.developer2blog.com/post/2012/08/14/Entity-framework-%28Basic%29.aspx) and [this](http://www.developer2blog.com/post/2012/11/17/Entity-framework-%28ONE-TO-MANY-RELATIONSHIP%29.aspx) for all your basic **CRUD (Create Read Update Delete)**  operation, in Entity framework. It will be very helpful to you. Also you can briefly understand the foreign key funda and one to many relationships.