# Controller unwantedly creates new user in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

On my MVC4 application I have a page where an user can be placed in a schedule. The idea is that you can select a person and that they will be entered on the schedule. The Schedule Model looks as follows:

```
public class Schedule {
    [Key]
    public int scheduleId { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The User Model where the Schedule Model refers to looks like this:

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Naam")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Beschikbaar")]
    public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

An user can be placed on the scheduling page with the following controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Schedule schedule)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Schedules.Add(schedule);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(schedule);
}
```

The Schedule/Create view looks like this:

[image: Schedule/Create]

and has the following code:

```
<h2>Schedule a person</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Schedule</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("UserId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.isAvailable)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.isAvailable)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.isAvailable)
         </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Plan" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

This code does place the user on the schedule on the specified date. But somehow an *extra* "null" user is created in the database every time an existing user is added to the schedule. See this image:

[image: This is the image which shows an extra user is created unwantedly]

I have been breaking my head over this unwanted behaviour for the past hours. The Create action of the ScheduleController does not specify to create an extra user. I have no idea why it does do so anyway.

Does anyone here have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point right before calling the insert database query? When it tries to insert a null, check the call stack. The error might not be where you think it is. (you have two UserId, maybe this cause confusion in the save function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your .User.IsAvailabe property. This creates a new user when adding the schedule.

You'll have to [attach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309835/entity-framework-duplicate-parentone-when-create-new-childmany) the existing user to your schedule. Perhaps you can even get rid of UserId and use User.Id in your form.